# On click of drop-down all the drop downs are opening in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used onClick to change the classname in css. I have used same classname for all the features. So onClick a particular feature I want that features submenus to dropdown not all the features. How can I get this done so that I could only open a particular feature's submenu. I have even attached the snip where I have clicked just the feature-2, but all the features are opened.-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayPcI.png

```js
import {React,useState,useEffect,useCallback }  from 'react';
import { Tabs } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';


const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const Navbar = (props) => {

    const [inactive, setInactive] = useState(true);
    const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
    const [focusingPaneKey, setFocusingPaneKey] = useState('')
    const [openingPaneKeys, setOpeningPaneKeys] = useState([])
  
    const openPane = (paneKey) => {
      setOpeningPaneKeys(oldState => {
        if (!oldState.includes(paneKey)) {
          return [...oldState, paneKey]
        }
        return oldState
      })
  
      setFocusingPaneKey(paneKey)
    }
  
    const closePane = (paneKey) => {
      if (paneKey === focusingPaneKey) {
        const paneKeyIndex = openingPaneKeys.indexOf(paneKey)
        setFocusingPaneKey(openingPaneKeys[paneKeyIndex - 1])
      }
  
      setOpeningPaneKeys(openingPaneKeys.filter((openingPaneKey) => openingPaneKey !== paneKey))
    }
  
    const handleTabsEdit = useCallback((key, action) => {
      if (action === 'remove') {
        closePane(key)
      }
    }, [closePane])
  
    
    
    useEffect(() => {
        if(inactive) {
            document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu").forEach((el) => {
                el.classList.remove("active");
            });
        }

        props.onCollapse(inactive);
    }, [inactive]);


    // const { panes } = props
    const keysOfPane = Object.keys(panes)

    return (
        <><div className={`side-navbar ${inactive ? "inactive" : ""}`}>
            <div className="top-section">
                <div onClick={() => { setInactive(!inactive); } } className="menu-btn">
                    {inactive ? (
                        <i class="bx bx-menu"></i>
                    ) : (
                        <i class='bx bx-x'></i>)}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="search-box">
                <button className="search-btn">
                    <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
                </button>
                <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
            </div>

            <div className="divider"></div>

            <div className="main-menu">
                <ul> 
                    <li>
                        <a onClick={() => openPane('1')} className="menu-item">
                            <div className="menu-icon">
                                <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <span>Feature-1</span>
                            
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <li onClick ={() => setExpand(!expand)}>
                        <a onClick={() => openPane('2')} className="menu-item">
                            <div  className="menu-icon">
                                <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <span>Feature-2</span>
                            <div className="drop-down">
                                <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-1</a> </li>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-2</a> </li>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-3</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    {/* <MenuItem
     name = {" Feature-2 "}
     subMenus = {[
         {name: "sub-menu-1"},{name: "sub-menu-2"},{name: "sub-menu-3"}
        ]}
     /> */}

                    <li onClick ={() => setExpand(!expand)}>
                        <a className="menu-item">
                            <div className="menu-icon">
                                <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                            </div>
                            <span>Feature-3</span>
                            <div className="drop-down">
                                <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-1</a> </li>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-2</a> </li>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-3</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li onClick ={() => setExpand(!expand)}>
                        <a className="menu-item">
                            <div className="menu-icon">
                                <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                            </div>
                            <span>Feature-4</span>
                            <div className="drop-down">
                                <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-1</a> </li>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-2</a> </li>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-3</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
        <div>
        <Tabs
            hideAdd
            onChange={openPane}
            activeKey={focusingPaneKey}
            type="editable-card"
            onEdit={handleTabsEdit}
        >
                {openingPaneKeys
                    .map((key) => panes[key])
                    .map((pane) => (
                        <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
                            {pane.content}
                        </TabPane>
                    ))}
            </Tabs>
            </div>
            </>
    );
};

const panes = {
    1: { key: '1', title: 'Feature 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1' },
    2: { key: '2', title: 'Feature 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2' },
    3: { key: '3', title: 'Feature 3', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 3' },
  }
  


export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move Feature section outside and create new component that will help you handle each Feature's state individually.

```
import {React,useState,useEffect,useCallback }  from 'react';
import { Tabs } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const NavBarLi = (props) => {
  const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);

  return (
    <li onClick ={() => setExpand(!expand) }>
        <a onClick={() => props.openPane('2')} className="menu-item">
          <div  className="menu-icon">
              <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
          </div>
          
          <span>Feature-2</span>
          <div className="drop-down">
              <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
          </div>
      </a>
      <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand ? 'active' : ""}`}>
        {props.children}
      </ul>
    </li>
  )
}

const Navbar = (props) => {
  ...

  return (
        <>
            ...
            <div className="main-menu">
                <ul> 
                    <li>
                        <a onClick={() => openPane('1')} className="menu-item">
                            <div className="menu-icon">
                                <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                            </div>
                            
                            <span>Feature-1</span>
                            
                        </a>
                    </li>

                    <NavBarLi openPane={openPane}>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-1</a> </li>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-2</a> </li>
                            <li> <a>sub-menu-3</a> </li>
                    </NavBarLi>

                    ...
                </ul>

            </div>

        </div>
        ...
        </>
    );
};

const panes = {
    1: { key: '1', title: 'Feature 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1' },
    2: { key: '2', title: 'Feature 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2' },
    3: { key: '3', title: 'Feature 3', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 3' },
  }

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined one `state` for all expandable items, you should define multiple `state` for every item:

```
import { React, useState, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import { Tabs } from "antd";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const Navbar = (props) => {
  const [inactive, setInactive] = useState(true);
  const [expand1, setExpand1] = useState(false);
  const [expand2, setExpand2] = useState(false);
  const [expand3, setExpand3] = useState(false);
  const [focusingPaneKey, setFocusingPaneKey] = useState("");
  const [openingPaneKeys, setOpeningPaneKeys] = useState([]);

  const openPane = (paneKey) => {
    setOpeningPaneKeys((oldState) => {
      if (!oldState.includes(paneKey)) {
        return [...oldState, paneKey];
      }
      return oldState;
    });

    setFocusingPaneKey(paneKey);
  };

  const closePane = (paneKey) => {
    if (paneKey === focusingPaneKey) {
      const paneKeyIndex = openingPaneKeys.indexOf(paneKey);
      setFocusingPaneKey(openingPaneKeys[paneKeyIndex - 1]);
    }

    setOpeningPaneKeys(
      openingPaneKeys.filter((openingPaneKey) => openingPaneKey !== paneKey)
    );
  };

  const handleTabsEdit = useCallback(
    (key, action) => {
      if (action === "remove") {
        closePane(key);
      }
    },
    [closePane]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inactive) {
      document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu").forEach((el) => {
        el.classList.remove("active");
      });
    }

    // props.onCollapse(inactive);
  }, [inactive]);

  // const { panes } = props
  const keysOfPane = Object.keys(panes);

  return (
    <>
      <div className={`side-navbar ${inactive ? "inactive" : ""}`}>
        <div className="top-section">
          <div
            onClick={() => {
              setInactive(!inactive);
            }}
            className="menu-btn"
          >
            {inactive ? <i class="bx bx-menu"></i> : <i class="bx bx-x"></i>}
          </div>
        </div>

        <div className="search-box">
          <button className="search-btn">
            <i class="bx bx-search"></i>
          </button>
          <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
        </div>

        <div className="divider"></div>

        <div className="main-menu">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a onClick={() => openPane("1")} className="menu-item">
                <div className="menu-icon">
                  <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
                </div>

                <span>Feature-1</span>
              </a>
            </li>

            <li onClick={() => setExpand1(!expand1)}>
              <a onClick={() => openPane("2")} className="menu-item">
                <div className="menu-icon">
                  <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
                </div>

                <span>Feature-2</span>
                <div className="drop-down">
                  <i class="bx bxs-down-arrow"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
              <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand1 ? "active" : ""}`}>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <a>sub-menu-1</a>{" "}
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <a>sub-menu-2</a>{" "}
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <a>sub-menu-3</a>{" "}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>

            {/* <MenuItem
     name = {" Feature-2 "}
     subMenus = {[
         {name: "sub-menu-1"},{name: "sub-menu-2"},{name: "sub-menu-3"}
        ]}
     /> */}

            <li onClick={() => setExpand2(!expand2)}>
              <a className="menu-item">
                <div className="menu-icon">
                  <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
                </div>
                <span>Feature-3</span>
                <div className="drop-down">
                  <i class="bx bxs-down-arrow"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
              <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand2 ? "active" : ""}`}>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <a>sub-menu-1</a>{" "}
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <a>sub-menu-2</a>{" "}
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <a>sub-menu-3</a>{" "}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li onClick={() => setExpand3(!expand3)}>
              <a className="menu-item">
                <div className="menu-icon">
                  <i class="bx bx-grid-alt"></i>
                </div>
                <span>Feature-4</span>
                <div className="drop-down">
                  <i class="bx bxs-down-arrow"></i>
                </div>
              </a>
              <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand3 ? "active" : ""}`}>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <a>sub-menu-1</a>{" "}
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <a>sub-menu-2</a>{" "}
                </li>
                <li>
                  {" "}
                  <a>sub-menu-3</a>{" "}
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Tabs
          hideAdd
          onChange={openPane}
          activeKey={focusingPaneKey}
          type="editable-card"
          onEdit={handleTabsEdit}
        >
          {openingPaneKeys
            .map((key) => panes[key])
            .map((pane) => (
              <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
                {pane.content}
              </TabPane>
            ))}
        </Tabs>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

const panes = {
  1: { key: "1", title: "Feature 1", content: "Content of Tab Pane 1" },
  2: { key: "2", title: "Feature 2", content: "Content of Tab Pane 2" },
  3: { key: "3", title: "Feature 3", content: "Content of Tab Pane 3" }
};

export default function App() {
  return <Navbar />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this, it will be fixed

```
import {React,useState,useEffect,useCallback }  from 'react';
import { Tabs } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const Navbar = (props) => {

const [inactive, setInactive] = useState(true);
const [expand, setExpand] = useState(false);
const [expand1, setExpand1] = useState(false);
const [expand2, setExpand2] = useState(false);

const [focusingPaneKey, setFocusingPaneKey] = useState('')
const [openingPaneKeys, setOpeningPaneKeys] = useState([])

const openPane = (paneKey) => {
  setOpeningPaneKeys(oldState => {
    if (!oldState.includes(paneKey)) {
      return [...oldState, paneKey]
    }
    return oldState
  })

  setFocusingPaneKey(paneKey)
}

const closePane = (paneKey) => {
  if (paneKey === focusingPaneKey) {
    const paneKeyIndex = openingPaneKeys.indexOf(paneKey)
    setFocusingPaneKey(openingPaneKeys[paneKeyIndex - 1])
  }

  setOpeningPaneKeys(openingPaneKeys.filter((openingPaneKey) => openingPaneKey !== paneKey))
}

const handleTabsEdit = useCallback((key, action) => {
  if (action === 'remove') {
    closePane(key)
  }
}, [closePane])



useEffect(() => {
    if(inactive) {
        document.querySelectorAll(".sub-menu").forEach((el) => {
            el.classList.remove("active");
        });
    }

    props.onCollapse(inactive);
}, [inactive]);


// const { panes } = props
const keysOfPane = Object.keys(panes)

return (
    <><div className={`side-navbar ${inactive ? "inactive" : ""}`}>
        <div className="top-section">
            <div onClick={() => { setInactive(!inactive); } } className="menu-btn">
                {inactive ? (
                    <i class="bx bx-menu"></i>
                ) : (
                    <i class='bx bx-x'></i>)}
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="search-box">
            <button className="search-btn">
                <i class='bx bx-search'></i>
            </button>
            <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
        </div>

        <div className="divider"></div>

        <div className="main-menu">
            <ul> 
                <li>
                    <a onClick={() => openPane('1')} className="menu-item">
                        <div className="menu-icon">
                            <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                        </div>
                        
                        <span>Feature-1</span>
                        
                    </a>
                </li>

                <li onClick ={() => setExpand(!expand)}>
                    <a onClick={() => openPane('2')} className="menu-item">
                        <div  className="menu-icon">
                            <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                        </div>
                        
                        <span>Feature-2</span>
                        <div className="drop-down">
                            <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                        <li> <a>sub-menu-1</a> </li>
                        <li> <a>sub-menu-2</a> </li>
                        <li> <a>sub-menu-3</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

                {/* <MenuItem
 name = {" Feature-2 "}
 subMenus = {[
     {name: "sub-menu-1"},{name: "sub-menu-2"},{name: "sub-menu-3"}
    ]}
 /> */}

                <li onClick ={() => setExpand1(!expand1)}>
                    <a className="menu-item">
                        <div className="menu-icon">
                            <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                        </div>
                        <span>Feature-3</span>
                        <div className="drop-down">
                            <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand1 ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                        <li> <a>sub-menu-1</a> </li>
                        <li> <a>sub-menu-2</a> </li>
                        <li> <a>sub-menu-3</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li onClick ={() => setExpand2(!expand2)}>
                    <a className="menu-item">
                        <div className="menu-icon">
                            <i class='bx bx-grid-alt'></i>
                        </div>
                        <span>Feature-4</span>
                        <div className="drop-down">
                            <i class='bx bxs-down-arrow'></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <ul className={`sub-menu ${expand2 ? 'active' : ""}`}>
                        <li> <a>sub-menu-1</a> </li>
                        <li> <a>sub-menu-2</a> </li>
                        <li> <a>sub-menu-3</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>

            </ul>

        </div>

    </div>
    <div>
    <Tabs
        hideAdd
        onChange={openPane}
        activeKey={focusingPaneKey}
        type="editable-card"
        onEdit={handleTabsEdit}
    >
            {openingPaneKeys
                .map((key) => panes[key])
                .map((pane) => (
                    <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
                        {pane.content}
                    </TabPane>
                ))}
        </Tabs>
        </div>
        </>
      );
 };

 const panes = {
1: { key: '1', title: 'Feature 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1' },
2: { key: '2', title: 'Feature 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2' },
3: { key: '3', title: 'Feature 3', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 3' },
}

export default Navbar;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have used a single state i.e clicked for all of the menu items, this will triger for all the menus when there is a setState called.

you should have seperate state for checking the clicks for each menu items. or make an array say clicked[] . and then change the value of a particular clicked state.

**For Example:**

```
<div className="menu-bar-item" ref="megaMenu">
            <a className="menu-bar-link" href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this,1)}>Second Menu</a>
            <div className={"mega-menu"+" "+this.state.clicked[1]}>
              <div className="mega-menu-content">
                <p>Second Menu</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

and define the handleClick as

```
handleClick(index,e) {
  let clicked=this.state.clicked;
    clicked[index]=!clicked[index]
    this.setState({clicked:clicked});
  }
```